# Can't click links, suspecting z-index issue

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have read a lot of posts here about z-index, but I can't manage to solve my problem. 
I can't click the links on my web-page. 
There is a link where it says "Klubbmesterskap" and where it says "Klikk her", but it is unresponsive.

Does anybody have a tip for me?

```css
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,a {
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-weight: 400;
}

body {
    width: 1200px;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
}

#header-image {
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url(logo.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 300px;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#nav {
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 150px;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

div#main {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    padding: 80px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#table_eldre_resultat {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    position: relative;
    padding: 80px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 170px;
    position: relative;
}

li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: #1da6e0;
    position: relative;
}

li:focus {
    background-color: #1da6e0;
    position: relative;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: white;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #333333;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #1da6e0;
    color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
    color: #1da6e0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: white;
}

input {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Lato";
    padding: 12px 16px;
    width: 250px;
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

#button {
    background-color: #1da6e0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    border: none;
}

.medlem {
    padding: 80px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    min-height: 860px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
}

h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.table {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
}

th {
    background-color: #1da6e0;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

td {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

label {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
}

.button {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #1da6e0;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

textarea {
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 300px;
}

#contactform {
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.contactform {
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    margin: 10px;
    position: inherit;
    left: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}

.placeholder {
    color: green;
}

select {
    width: 300px;
    font-family: "Lato";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style-type: none;
}

option {
    border: none;
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 300px;
}

#result_left {
    width: 45%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

#result_right {
    width: 45%;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}

.result {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

img {
    margin: 30px;
    border: 3px solid #1da6e0;
}

#img_tg {
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#torsdagsgolf {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#img_km {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 400px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    right: 0;
}

#km {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

#hio {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    width: 50%;
}

#br {
    width: 50%;
}

#br_hio_img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    right: 0;
}

#grasrot {
    border: none;
}

#grasrot_link {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #1da6e0;
}

#grasrot_link:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Selje Golklubb</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body onload="ClearForm()">
        <!-- HEADER -->
        <div id="header-image">
            <!-- Navigasjonsbar -->
            <div id="nav">
                <ul class="navbar">
                    <li>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="dropbtn">Klubben</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <a href="omoss.html">Om oss</a>
                                <a href="klubbmestere.html">Klubbmestere</a>
                                <a href="holeinone.html">Hole in One</a>
                                <a href="grasrotandelen.html">Grasrotandelen</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="dropbtn">Medlem</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <a href="medlemskap.html">Medlemskap / priser</a>
                                <a href="innmeldingskjema.html">Innmeldingskjema</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="dropbtn">Banen</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <a href="banekart.html">Banekart</a>
                                <a href="filer/scorekort.pdf">Scorekort</a>
                                <a href="filer/slopeherrer.pdf">Slopetabell herrer</a>
                                <a href="filer/slopedamer.pdf">Slopetabell damer</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="dropbtn">Turnering</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <a href="terminliste.html">Terminliste</a>
                                <a href="torsdagsgolf.html">Torsdagsgolf</a>
                                <a href="eldre_resultater.html">Eldre resultater</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="sistenytt.html">Siste nytt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="kontaktoss.html">Kontakt</a></li>

                    <!-- INNLOGGING GOLFBOX -->
                    <li>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="dropbtn">Golfbox</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <form action="http://golfbox.no/login.asp" method="post" target="_blank" id="golfbox-login" autocomplete="off">
                                    <input id="loginboxusername" type="text" class="form-control" name="loginform.username" value="" placeholder="Brukernavn"></input>
                                    <input id="loginboxpasswd" type="password" class="form-control" name="loginform.password" value="" placeholder="Passord"></input>
                                    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Logg inn"></input>
                                    <input type="hidden" value="true" name="loginform.submitted" id="loginform.submitted">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="http://norskgolf.newsfront.no" name="redirect" id="redirect">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="login" name="command" id="command">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Slutt på innlogging golfbox -->

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Slutt på navigasjonsbar -->
        </div>
        <!-- slutt på header-image -->

        <!-- HOVEDINNHOLD -->
        <div id="main">
            <table class="table">

                <thead>

                    <tr>

                        <th>Dato</th>

                        <th>Turnering</th>

                        <th>Spilleform</th>

                        <th>Starttid</th>

                        <th>Påmeldingsfrist</th>

                        <th>Kontigent</th>

                        <th>Resultater</th>

                    </tr>

                </thead>

                <tbody>

                    <tr>

                        <td>18.04.2017</td>

                        <td>Sommerkarusell 2017</td>

                        <td>Stableford</td>

                        <td>18.30</td>

                        <td>*</td>

                        <td>250,-</td>

                        <td><a href="http://www.golfbox.no/livescoring/tour/?language=1044#/competition/295290/results">Klikk her</a></td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td>01.05.2017</td>

                        <td>Åpningsturnering</td>

                        <td>Par-scramble</td>

                        <td>11.00</td>

                        <td>30.04.2014 kl 18:00</td>

                        <td>200,-</td>
                        <td> </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td>21.05.2017</td>

                        <td>NordVest Tour - Selje Open</td>

                        <td>Brutto og stableford</td>

                        <td>11.00</td>

                        <td>13.05.2017 kl 18:00</td>

                        <td>200,-</td>
                        <td> </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td>12.06.2017</td>

                        <td>Nordea Pairs</td>
                      
                        <td>Parturnering, stableford, fourball</td>

                        <td>11.00</td>

                        <td>13.06.2017 kl 18:00</td>

                        <td>200,-</td>
                        <td> </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td>09.08.2017</td>

                        <td>Parturnering</td>

                        <td>Scramble, fourball og foursome</td>

                        <td>11.00</td>

                        <td>08.08.2017 kl 18:00</td>

                        <td>200,-</td>
                        <td> </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td>27.08.2017</td>

                        <td><a href="http://www.golfbox.no/livescoring/tour/?language=1044#/competition/287213/info">Klubbmesterskap</a></td>

                        <td>Brutto slag</td>

                        <td>11.00</td>

                        <td>05.09.2017 kl 18:00</td>

                        <td>200,-</td>
                        <td> </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td>06.09.2017</td>

                        <td>Trisome </td>

                        <td>Mer info kommer...</td>

                        <td>*</td>

                        <td>*</td>

                        <td>*</td>
                        <td> </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td>27.09.2017</td>

                        <td>Selje Pairs</td>

                        <td>Greensome, stableford</td>

                        <td>11.00</td>

                        <td>26.09.2017 kl 18:00</td>

                        <td>200,-</td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- Slutt på hovedinnhold -->
        <div id="footer">
            <a href="http://pbortne.no/">© 2016 pbortne.no</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to right-click on the link and then click "inspect element" (in chrome).  If you inspect the link, then your link is positioned fine, if you happen to click on something else, then you have a z-index problem.  What do you inspect if you do that?

Comment: I don't see you setting z-index anywhere.  Consider turning this into a fiddle.

Comment: I am inspecting the body-tag.

Comment: works fine for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRymqK

Comment: Try here: http://pbortne.no/seljegk3/terminliste.html

Comment: On your site, the links  "Klubbmesterskap" and "Klikk her" are in working order in both browsers. So, what browser did you test?

Comment: I am using Chrome, and also tried Safari.

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-content {
   z-index:9999;
 }
```

Add what ever number you want for z-index.

[Lear more here about z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Hello all and thanks for your help. 
Seems like it was no z-index issue at all. 
My body tag was like this

```
<body onload="ClearForm()">
```

When I removed it, everything was working just fine :)

Guess I will have to find another way to clear my forms when I load the page.

Thanks again!